# SymmetricDS Syncing is not syncing perfectly

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I have a 3 server running SymmetricDS. Say i have node 1 which is master, node 2.node 3 are child.

When some data is being inserted into node 2 it's being synced to node 1 and similarly node 3's data is being syncing with node 1. But node 2 data is not going to node 3.

I do not know where to solve this issue. Here is the sample configuration sql

```
        -- =========================================
        -- channel starts

        insert into sym_channel
        (channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
        values('acc', 1, 100000, 1, 'account sample');

        -- =========================================
        -- channel ends



        -- =========================================
        -- group starts

        insert into sym_node_group
              (node_group_id, description)
              values ('corp', 'A corporate node');
        insert into sym_node_group
              (node_group_id, description)
              values ('store', 'A retail store node');
        -- group ends
        -- =========================================




        -- =========================================
        -- Group links starts

        insert into sym_node_group_link
        (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action)
              values ('store', 'corp', 'P');
        insert into sym_node_group_link
        (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action)
              values ('corp', 'store', 'W');

        -- Group link ends
        -- =========================================



        -- =========================================
        -- trigger starts
        insert into  
        sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_table_name, channel_id, last_update_time,  create_time) 
        values      ('a1',     'acc_asi',        'acc',   current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        insert into  
        sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_table_name, channel_id, last_update_time,  create_time) 
        values      ('a2',     'acc_lop_asi',        'acc',   current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        -- =========================================
        -- trigger ends




        -- =========================================
        -- router starts
        insert into sym_router 
        (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
        values('corp_2_store', 'corp', 'store', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
        insert into sym_router 
        (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
        values('store_2_corp', 'store', 'corp', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
        -- router ends
        -- =========================================



        -- =========================================
        -- trigger router starts

        insert into sym_trigger_router 
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time) 
        values ('a1', 'store_2_corp', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        insert into sym_trigger_router 
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time) 
        values ('a2', 'store_2_corp', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        insert into sym_trigger_router 
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time) 
        values ('a1', 'corp_2_store', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        insert into sym_trigger_router 
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time) 
        values ('a2', 'corp_2_store', 1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

        -- =========================================
        -- trigger router ends
```

It would be very helpful if i can know how to push node 2's  data to node 3. or  node 2 push data on node 1 and then node 1 push those data to node 3

Regards,

Nixon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `sym_trigger`'s column `sync_on_incoming_batch` to 1 for the tables needed to get synced from 2 to 3 and vice-versa via master 1.

Comment: thanks that did the trick. But i also found another solution which is like this,  create a new group link from
 `STORE_TO_STORE
(source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action)
      values ('store', 'store', 'P');`

Check out the documentation for more information on both setups.
https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_table_triggers