# SymmetricDS: sync client nodes to each other

Tags: symmetricds

I have symmetricDS configured so that there is one master node in the cloud, and then two "store" (client) nodes in remote locations.

If I insert data in the cloud, it is syncd to both clients. If I insert data in a client, it is syncd to the cloud.

However, data added on client1 never makes it to client2 and data added on client2 never makes it to client1...

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: This answer worked for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675721/882168

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would want a second set of triggers (maybe prefix each with the name cloud_*) that has an additional flag turned on sym_trigger.sync_on_incoming_batch=1.   This will cause changes coming in as part of replication from client 1..n to be captured and resent to all other clients.

This can be more efficient that a client to client group link solution because usually the clients do not all have access over a network to sync to each other.  So the change would sync to the cloud and then be redistributed to the other clients.